# Using Google Authentication for Multiple C# ASP.NET Web apps

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I have multiple non-authenticating ASP.NET applications running in my organization's environment. We'd like to authenticate users for these apps using Google authentication. As new .NET apps come online, we'd like to have them authenticate using the same method.

I have successfully created Google authentication using individual emails (e.g., person@gmail.com) by creating a project in Visual Studio. It works, but this approach doesn't work for an organization, and is for one web app only.

How can I create a single authentication piece and apply it to multiple .NET apps? I'm not looking for code, but a general list of how to go about it with any URLs you may have that describe it in detail. Thank you.